# Backbone view not updating

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following Backbone view and when I intialize it I load my template

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.products'),
    template: _.template($('#products-template').html()),
    sortKey: 'id',
    events: {
        "click .sort": "sortProducts"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'appendItem', 'loadMore');

        $(this.el).html(this.template({sortKey: this.sortKey}));
        this.collection = new List();
    },

    sortProducts: function(e) {
        this.sortKey = $(e.currentTarget).data('sort');
        e.preventDefault();
    },
```

In my view I echo out the value of sortKey

```
<%-sortKey %>
```

This works fine when I first load the page but when the sortKey changes when the `sortProducts` function is trigger the view doesn't update with the new value of `sortKey`.

I thought Backbone was meant to update the view automatically?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: _I thought Backbone was meant to update the view automatically_ No, that's not so. You have to bind data changing and View rendering manually. But first, you have to place `sortKey` variable into a Model and bind it with the View.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone doesn't automatically update your view, you have to tell it to.

```
sortProducts: function(e) {
    this.sortKey = $(e.currentTarget).data('sort');
    e.preventDefault();
    this.render();
}
```

You can set up automatic update by listening to events:

```
// example of updating the view when the model changes
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

Also, you should move the template/render into the `render` function:

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template({sortKey: this.sortKey}));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, still trying to get my head around it but this helped and explained it well.